# App Refuses to Install - INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY

Tags: android, android-studio, mpandroidchart, android-install-apk

I am new to programming generally please I need some help!
My app was installing successfully after every update until i decided to add the 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.1.0-alpha' library to the app because i need the user to be able to view some data in form of statistical charts.

The library was synced successfully and have used packages and classes therein successful. But when i try to install the app in my android device it returned this error:

```
Installation failed with message Failed to commit install session 590492354 with command cmd package
install-commit 590492354. Error: INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY: Package couldn't be installed in
/data/app/com.cenitscitech.www.etimebook-jOP-jv2YuNu7_8qnkfqp-A==: Package com.cenitscitech.www.etimebook requires unavailable shared library com.google.android.things; failing!.
```

It is possible that this issue is resolved by uninstalling an existing version of the apk if it is present, and then re-installing." I have pasted a screenshot here:

[image: The Error message:]

I uninstalled the existing version of the apk, cleared some memory space but keep on getting the same message! What should I do next please?

Comment: Can you update your question to include your `AndroidManifest.xml` file?

Comment: Yes @kenny_k , the trouble is found to be in the manifest file as given by ahasbini. this entry: <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.things" />, was in the manifest file and had to be removed before the installation was successful. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are most likely installing on a device that is not an Android Things device. I suspect the library you added either has some transitive dependency on `com.google.android.things`, or something else changed in your project.

To get around this, you must do the following 2 things:

**1.** Mark that Android Things is not required on the device in your `AndroidManifest.xml` file:

```xml
<uses-library
   android:name="com.google.android.things"
   android:required="false"
   tools:replace="android:required" />
```

(`tools:replace` is not strictly required, but it just there in case something in the manifest merge process overrides your setting.)

**2.** In your app's code, before making any calls to the Things APIs, make sure that they are available on the current device. This can be tested with the following code snippet:

```java
public boolean isThingsDevice(Context context) {
    final PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
    return pm.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_EMBEDDED);
}
```

Only doing **1** should fix the install problem, but your app will crash if you make any Things API calls on a device that isn't an Android Things device.

Answer (score 2):

Had a look in the `com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.1.0-alpha` [repository](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/tree/v3.1.0-alpha) and did not find any reference to `com.google.android.things` inside the source code.

You need to remove the below entry in case it's found in the `AndroidManifest.xml` of your app for it to work on your device again:

```
<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.things" />
```

Comment: Please make sure you are using a library that works across different CPU's. Please go through the link below to verify this: https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2019/01/get-your-apps-ready-for-64-bit.html

Comment: @ahasbini, this has solved the issue yes! Thanks a lot!