# INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY Error When Trying To Run Android App

Tags: android-studio, android-things

I've never made an Android app before and I'm this isn't a great start.
I made a blank project on Android studios as a test and tried to run the program on my Huawei P33 phone. When I attempt to build and install the program, I get the following messages;

> Failed to commit install session 389180709 with command cmd package
>   install-commit 389180709. Error:
>   INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY: Package couldn't be installed
>   in /data/app/com.example.myapplication-segdjrVZj4KvtCNaJ5W5oQ==:
>   Package com.example.myapplication requires unavailable shared library
>   com.google.android.things; failing!
>
> Session 'app': Installation did not succeed.
>                     The application could not be installed: INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY
>                     Retry

I've spent about an hour and a half googling, but no one has seemed to have the same issue with the Android Things library.

In 'AndroidManifest.xml', if I change `<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.things" />` to `<uses-library android:name="com.google.android" />`, the app installs but does nothing and crashes as soon as it is opened.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58148317/app-refuses-to-install-install-failed-missing-shared-library/58346732#58346732

Comment: I too found problem with Huawei p40 lite

Answer (score 14):

Please go to your manifest file and see if these lines of code are there. If present please delete them.

```
enter c<uses-library
        android:name="com.google.android.wearable"
        android:required="true" />

    <!--
           Set to true if your app is Standalone, that is, it does not require the handheld
           app to run.
    -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.wearable.standalone"
        android:value="true" />
```

Comment: Android-studio added these wearable lines after I tried adding a blank Activity from the right-click menu --- and messed up the activity's XML. When I selected *Empty Activity* from the gallery, it worked, but left these lines in the manifest.

Answer (score 2):

Given that you've never made an Android app before, it's likely that you picked an Android Things template on the new project Wizard.
Just create a new project and make sure to select just phone and tablet, not Android Things.

Answer (score 0):

I think you deleted an element that is still in the manifest.

for example u deleted activity, and element is still in the manifest.

```
  <activity
        android:name=".players"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_players">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```